# What are correct values for precision and recall when the denominators equal 0?

Tags: precision-recall

Precision is defined as:

> p = true positives / (true positives + false positives)

What is the value of precision if (true positives + false positives) = 0? Is it just undefined?

Same question for recall:

> r = true positives / (true positives + false negatives)

In this case, what is the value of recall if (true positives + false negatives) = 0?

P.S. This question is very similar to the question [What are correct values for precision and recall in edge cases?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/what-are-correct-values-for-precision-and-recall-in-edge-cases).

Comment: Heh, it is even answered in the duplicate; but let's call it a good duplicate.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answers to the linked earlier question apply here too.

If (true positives + false negatives) = 0 then no positive cases in the input data, so any analysis of this case has no information, and so no conclusion about how positive cases are handled.  You want N/A or something similar as the ratio result, avoiding a *division by zero* error

If (true positives + false positives) = 0 then all cases have been predicted to be negative: this is one end of the ROC curve. Again, you want to recognise and report this possibility while avoiding a *division by zero* error.

Comment: Thanks Henry for the answer. If I understand correctly, in the former case, you **do not** want to recognize and report the result, whereas in the latter case you **do**. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes: In the no-positives-in-input case, precision is meaningless; in the no-positives-predicted case, you want to report that the test has been set to be extremely negative.

Comment: I like the added intuition of "no information" vs "information" in the two cases. I wonder why scikit-learn handles these with replacing div by zero with 1 or 0?

Answer (score 12):

An interesting answer is offered here:
https://github.com/dice-group/gerbil/wiki/Precision,-Recall-and-F1-measure

The authors of the module output different scores for precision and recall depending on whether true positives, false positives and false negatives are **all** 0. If they are, the outcome is ostensibly a good one.

> In some rare cases, the calculation of Precision or Recall can cause a
>   division by 0. Regarding the precision, this can happen if there are
>   no results inside the answer of an annotator and, thus, the true as
>   well as the false positives are 0. For these special cases, we have
>   defined that if the true positives, false positives and false
>   negatives are all 0, the precision, recall and F1-measure are 1. This
>   might occur in cases in which the gold standard contains a document
>   without any annotations and the annotator (correctly) returns no
>   annotations. If true positives are 0 and one of the two other counters
>   is larger than 0, the precision, recall and F1-measure are 0.

I'm not sure if this type of scoring would be useful in other situations outside of their special case, but it's worth some thought.

Comment: I think this makes sense for any application. Here "annotations" stand-in for "relevant cases". Nice find. I'd like to see how they handle the recall situation, so I'll click the link.

Answer (score 3):

When evaluating a classifier at high thresholds, the precision might (often actually) not be 1 when recall is 0. It's usually N/A!
I think there is something wrong about how people plot the P/R curve. Avoiding N/A samples is a bias in the sense that you avoid singularity samples. I computed the average precision wrt to the average recall ignoring N/A samples and I never got a classifier starting at 1 for 0 recall for a shallow neural net in object detection. This was also true for curves computed with the tp,fp,fn numbers. It's quite easy to verify by paper and pencil with a single image. For example:
I have a classifier that outputs for a single image:
preds=[.7 .6 .5 .1 .05]
truth=[n  y   n  n  y ]
By computing the confusion matrices with the various thresholds we have:
tp=[2 1 1 1 0 0],fn=[0 1 1 1 2 2],fp=[3 3 2 1 1 0].
the recall rec=[1 .5 .5 .5 0 0], and the precision=[.4 .25 1/3 .5 0 NaN].
I don't see how it would make sense to replace a NaN or the precision(@recall==0) with 1. 1 should be an upper bound, not a value we replace precision(@recall==0) with.